# Two ways to calculate probability of pulling 2 cards out of a deck - why different results?

Tags: probability

Let's say you wanted to know the probability of pulling out a Heart and a red card out of a standard shuffled deck of 52 cards, in that order.

Option 1: 13/52 * 25/51 = 12.2%
Option 2: (13 choose 1) * (25 choose 1) / (52 choose 2) = 24.5%

I don't understand why the two methods arrive at results which are 2x apart. My hunch is telling me option 2 is wrong, but I don't know why:) Sorry if this is stupid but I just don't see what I'm missing!

Comment: When troubleshooting: Shrink the example down and compute it by hand. Say we've got only the aces, for example.

Comment: The order of cards is important, so (52 choose 2) need to be replaced by 52x51.

Comment: The denominator for the second gives the number of unordered pairs, which is half the number of the ordered pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, in the second case you divided the number of favourable *ordered* pairs by the total number of *unordered* pairs.